# Generate random number in multiple text files

Tags: c++

what I'm trying to do is generate random numbers in multiple text files, here's my current code:

```
// Write files
        string file_name_write = "2016\\Sem2\\Timetable_list\\Timetable" + s->Get_subid() + ".txt";
        ofstream fo (file_name_write.c_str()); // E.g: Timetable_list\TimetableICT1.1.txt
        fo << "Subject ID: " << s->Get_subid() << endl;
        fo << "Subject name: " << s->Get_name() << endl;
        fo << "Lecturer: " << s->lecturer << endl;
        fo << "Venue: " << s->venue << endl;
        fo << "Time: " << s->time << endl << endl; 
        fo << "List of students for this subject:" << endl;
        fo << "Order    ID  Name        DOB     Address     E.Year  Major   Midterm Final   Total" << endl;
        int n = s->number_of_students; 
        Student *temp_stu;
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
        {
            int random_mid;
            int random_final;
            random_mid = (rand() % 20) + 1;
            random_final = (rand() % 20) + 1;
            temp_stu = lstu.Find_Student (s->stu_id[i]);
            fo << i+1 << "  " << temp_stu->Get_pid() << "   " << temp_stu->Get_fname() << " "
               << temp_stu->Get_dob() << "  " << temp_stu->Get_addr() << "      "
               << temp_stu->Get_ent_year() << " " << temp_stu->Get_major() << " " << random_mid 
               << " " << random_final << endl;
        }
        fo.close();
        s = s -> next;
```

The problem I'm having is the lists of random numbers in my text files are exactly the same. For example, every single one of my files generate these same numbers:

```
Midterm Final
  14     16
  12     5
  5      1
  12     15
  19     18
```

I want my program to generate different lists of numbers in each of my text files, any idea how can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Is this being done in a loop \ multiple function call by chance?

Comment: @NathanOliver Suggesting that the seed is at the same time always because `time(...` has second resolution?

Comment: no, it's not. @NathanOliver

Comment: Then please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

Call to time(NULL) will return seconds, so your code re-initializes PRNG multiple times during the same second with the same seed. Just an example:

```
srand (33); // initialize with a fixed seed = 33.
printf ("random number: %d, %d, %d\n", rand()%100, rand()%100, rand()%100);
// > random number: 41, 15, 22

srand (33); // re-initialize with the same seed = 33.
printf ("random number: %d, %d, %d\n", rand()%100, rand()%100, rand()%100);
// > random number: 41, 15, 22
```

You have to initialize PRNG only once, on the application start:

```
int main () {
    srand(time(NULL));
    ... // other code
```